# How to remove a workspace in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powerbi

I'm aware of the existence of `Remove-PowerBIWorkspaceUser` and `Remove-PowerBIReport`, but I couldn't find any cmdlet to delete an enitre workspace, something like `Remove-PowerBIWorkspace` (which does not exist).

Is there any command to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, there is no such CmdLet. You must call the [Power BI REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/groups/delete-group) directly, using [Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoftpowerbimgmt.profile/invoke-powerbirestmethod?view=powerbi-ps) CmdLet, for example like this:

```
Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" -Method Delete
```

(where `xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx` is the ID of the workspace to be deleted)

Comment: thanks for answering! I'm getting 401 Unauthorized error even tho I'm admin. Is there any particular previous step such as getting a token or something?

Comment: No, there are no other steps necessary (except login into Power BI, of course). If you have rights to delete the workspace, the code above is all you need. You can [try to call the API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/groups/delete-group#code-try-0) in the site and see the response to find out why you get 401. You can do that with a tool like Fidler for example and see the response returned by Power BI to your request sent with the PowerShell script.

Comment: Thanks! Turns out I have to be admin of the workspace as well, not just admin of the server. [With this API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/admin/groups-add-user-as-admin) I can get admin membership of the workspace and then delete it with your code